# Combinatorical surface is restricted to a closed face an injection

Tags: co.combinatorics, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello :)
I'm third year student of mathematics. In my own intrest i'm studying topology in combinatorical sense. Herefore i found also an lecture note in knot theory from Roberts. I want to understand all the steps but there is one exercise i don't understand (thus i can't solve it). Can someone help me? Here the question:

*Suppose $T_i$ are triangles and $\coprod{T_i}$ the disjoint union. Then we can choose an equivalencerelation to get a combinatorical surface $F$, thus there is a map $\coprod{T_i}\rightarrow F$. A closed surface $F$ made by gluing triangles is called a closed combinatorial
surface if the union of the (closed) faces incident at any vertex of $F$, thought of as a subspace of $F$, is a cone. A cone is a surface with boundary made by gluing $d$ faces arranged around a common vertex, for some $d\geq3$. Now i want to prove the following:*

**$\coprod{T_i}\rightarrow F$ is restricted to a closed face an injection (thus no face is glued to itself) and any two distinct closed faces of $F$ meet in either a single common edge, a single common vertex, or are disjoint.**

I hope someone can help me?!
Thank you

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for MathOverflow, which is intended for questions of interest to research mathematicians; see the FAQ. You will get at best very terse answers, and perhaps no answer at all. I suggest trying math.stackexchange.com instead, where you are likely to get more in depth answers.